# how do i send timestamp in correct format from RTC to website in a Get request? using arduino

Tags: c#, asp.net, timestamp, arduino

Hi i have been trying to send data from my arduino to my ASP.Net website and have been successful until i try to send a timestamp as a variable in the GET request.

it is because asp.net expects: 01/01/01 01:01:01 and am sending 1/1/1 1:1:1. so i need to figure out how send it with the zero in front if needed

my arduino code so far (the sending part)

```
void sendLightData() {
  DateTime now = rtc.now();
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
    // no point in carrying on, so do nothing forevermore:
    // try to congifure using IP address instead of DHCP:
    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);
  }
  // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("connecting...");

  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.print("GET /LightData.aspx?uname=");
    client.print(userName);
    client.print("&pword=");
    client.print(password);
    client.print("&LStatus=");
    client.print(lightStatus);
    client.print("&LHeight=9&");
    client.print("timestamp=");
    client.print(now.day(), DEC);
    client.print("/");
    client.print(now.month(), DEC);
    client.print("/");
    client.print(now.year(), DEC);
    client.print("%20");
    client.print(now.hour(), DEC);
    client.print(":");
    client.print(now.minute(), DEC);
    client.print(":");
    client.print(now.second(), DEC); 
    client.println(" HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: www.auntieagie.eu");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
    // this works if entered into a browser (trying to replicate in arduino) http://auntieagie.eu/LightData.aspx?uname=test&pword=t&LStatus=1&LHeight=2&timestamp=21/02/2014%2001:01:01
  }
```

any help or a point in the right direction would be great

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
client.print(now.Date.ToString().Replace(" ", "%20"));
```

This will return a dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss replacing the space with the encoded character.

At least in Asp Net you have the HttpUtility, if you have access to that, you can use:
System.Web.HttpUtility

```
client.print(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(now.Date.ToString()));
```

The Day and Month will return a Int value, so, no left Zero is included.